lim_(x→ π/2 ) cos (5x)/( sin (2020x) sin (2021x) ) can someone help me solving this without using the L'Hôpital? tysm
lim_(x→ π/2 )  cos (5x)/( sin (2020x) sin (2021x) )  can someone help me solving this without using the L'Hôpital? tysm
